# How can I make a string of n 1's in tcl?

Tags: tcl

I need to make a string of n 1's in tcl where n is some variable, how can I do this nicely?

At the moment I'm doing this but there must be a better way.

```
set i 1
set ones 1
while {$i < $n} {
    set ones 1$ones
    incr i}
```

In python I'd write `"1"*n`.

Comment: `string repeat 1 $n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:[Simple Solution]**

```
set n 10
puts "[string repeat "1" $n]" ;# To display output on console
set output_str [string repeat "1" $n] ;# To get output in variable
```

**Solution 2:**

You have to `append` "one" inside string n number of times, where n is number of ones you want in string.

```
set n 10
set i 0
set ones 1
set output_str ""
while {$i < $n} {
    append output_str $ones
    incr i
}
```

Output,

```
puts $output_str ;#Gives output 1111111111
```

Comment: I can see that would work but I'm looking for something simple and that does it neatly in one or two lines. Python does it in 5 characters, it can't be that hard. Thank you.

Comment: Check newest edit. i thought you are getting syntax error in your given code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built in string command to do this:

```
% set n 10
10
% string repeat "1" $n
1111111111
%
```